# C# type arguments cannot be inferred

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

Learning about generics.. I have a generic array handler that allows various array manipulations on specific types. I was told to sort the test data using a constraint on T with `IComparable<T>` but couldn't figure it out where to put the condition so I just used `Sort<T>` which uses `IComparable<T>` (even if it gets the result it likely wasn't how I was supposed to make it).

Anyway, I also have a method to extract a section of an array, which is where the errors appear.
Such as this one:

> CS0411: The type arguments for method 'ArrayHelper_T.GetSubArray(T[], int, int)' cannot be
> inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

If I use the other one that I out-commented (Program/ Main) I get a different error I don't know how to fix either.
I read the msdn on generics and interfaces, and looked at similar error questions here but it didn't help me finding solutions.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayHelper_T<string> strings = new ArrayHelper_T<string>(size: 5);
        strings[0] = "cc";
        strings[1] = "bb";
        strings[2] = "aa";
        strings[3] = "ee";
        strings[4] = "dd";

        strings.SortPrintArray();

        int sub_start_index = 1;
        int sub_length = 3;
            
        ArrayHelper_T<string> sub_strings = new ArrayHelper_T<string>(sub_length);
        
        sub_strings = strings.GetSubArray(array: strings, index: sub_start_index, size: sub_length);
            
        //sub_strings = strings.GetSubArray<ArrayHelper_T<string>>
        //      (array: strings, index: sub_start_index, size: sub_length);
            
        sub_strings.SortPrintArray();
    }
}
```

```
public class ArrayHelper_T<T>
    // where T : IComparable<T>
    // , IEnumerable<T>
{
    private T[] array;

    public ArrayHelper_T(int size)
    {
        array = new T[size];
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return array[index]; }
        set { array[index] = value; }
    }
    
    public int Size
    {
        get { return array.Length; }
    }
    
    public void SortPrintArray() // where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if(array.Length > 1)
        {
            Array.Sort<T>(array);
            Console.WriteLine($"Sorted sub-vector: {string.Join("  ", array)} .\n");
        }
        else
        Console.WriteLine($"There is only one element: {array[0]} .\n");
    }

    public T[] GetSubArray<T>(T[] array, int index, int size)
    {
        if( ! (array is null) && (index >= 0 && index < array.Length) &&
            (size <= (array.Length - index + 1)) )
        {
            T[] t = new T[size];
                
            Array.Copy(array, index, t, 0, size);
            return t;
        }

        return Array.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

I also have a secondary question: how can I make the value initialization less blocky, in a single line such as `strings = {"cc", "bb", "aa", "ee", "dd"};`?

Comment: One of the errors is that `strings` if of type `ArrayHelper_T<string>` but you're expecting an array (`T[]`) on `GetSubArray`

Comment: Your second question: This will work if your class implements ICollection<T>.

Comment: Or, more generally (for the 2nd question), if your class implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` and has an `Add` method with an appropriate signature.  You can also have several overloads of `Add`, and allow variations on the initialization.  This is knows as the _Collection Initialization Pattern_: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers

Comment: You list an error.  On what line does it appear?

Comment: You have this code, declaring `sub_strings`: `ArrayHelper_T<string> sub_strings`.  Then, the next line is: `sub_strings = strings.GetSubArray(params)`.  But, `GetSubArray` returns a `T[]`, not a `ArrayHelper_T<T>`

Comment: @Magnetron If I don't expect an array how can I manipulate it? If I pass in `T` then in `ArrayHelper_T` how can I handle it as a collection/ array? Should I just expect the `int`-s? Then call as `var s = strings.GetSubArray(index, size)`?

Comment: @Flydog57 first, in `Program` class right above the comments. Thanks for the article I will read it and attempt the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a generic type parameter both for the class and on methods and you are mixing them up.

A correct type declaration would be

```
public class ArrayHelper_T<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private IReadOnlyList<T> array;

    ...

    public void SortPrintArray()
    {
        ...
    }

    public T[] GetSubArray( int index, int size)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Another alternative that would fit rather well for this example is to use extension methods. This skips over the need to wrap the array in a class, while still allowing you to call methods as if they where instance methods.

```
public static class ArrayHelper
{
    public static void SortPrintArray<T>(this T[] array) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        ...
    }

    public static T[] GetSubArray<T>(this T[] array, int index, int size)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

you might also want to implement a overload that takes a IComparer object. This can be useful since it allows the caller to specify how the objects should be compared. For example by comparing some property of the object instead of the objects themselves.

```
public class KeyComparer<T, TKey> : IComparer<T> where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    private readonly Func<T, TKey> selector;
    public KeyComparer(Func<T, TKey> selector) => this.selector = selector;
    public int Compare(T x, T y) => selector(x).CompareTo(selector(y));
}
 public static void SortPrintArray<T, TKey>(this T[] array, Func<T, TKey> selector) where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
        => SortPrintArray(array, new KeyComparer<T, TKey>(selector));
 public static void SortPrintArray<T>(this T[] array, IComparer<T> comparer) 
 {
        //...
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your examples. I tried your first block but it force me to alter the `SortPrintArray` to accept only arrays. Which is a problem as I use the same function on the initial object wrapped array too (wasn't in the snippet). The 3rd block sadly looks too complicated to my generics-beginner eyes.

Comment: @zsombor V If you want to use the same function for other kinds of lists than arrays I would recommend using an interface line `IReadOnlyList`, It might also be useful to implement the same interface, forming what is called a *decorator*. Updated the example to show this.